# How to pop a column on a dask dataframe?

Tags: dask

I have a huge dataframe (555M+) I want to split in a train and a test set. How can I split it so with something that reduce memory usage like pop ? I tried :

```
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    print("Before train test split")
    train_X, test_X = result.random_split([0.8, 0.2])
    print("Before train test split features target")
    train_Y = train_X.pop('TARGET')
    test_Y = test_X.pop('TARGET')
```

But infortunately it doesn't seem there is such a method on dask dataframes as I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pop'

This for a multi-class classification problem. If you have any tips I would be happy to here them as I struggle a lot ! You can find my repository [here](https://github.com/antoinecomp/multiclass_prediction).

Answer (score 0):

In the future for feature requests I recommend raising an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

I've added an implementation here: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5422